# SQL queries combined into one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some difficulty combining the following queries, so that the results display in one row rather than in multiple rows:

```
SELECT value FROM dbo.parameter WHERE name='xxxxx.name'
SELECT dbo.contest.name AS Event_Name
FROM contest
INNER JOIN open_box on open_box.contest_id = contest.id
GROUP BY dbo.contest.name

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM open_option AS total_people

SELECT SUM(scanned) AS TotalScanned,SUM(number) AS Totalnumber
FROM dbo.open_box
GROUP BY contest_id

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM open AS reff
WHERE refer = 'True'
```

I would like to display data from the fields in each column similar to what is shown in the image below. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: it's like transposing the thing. Do you want it multiple columns or just one field (sort of a concatenation) ?

Comment: Welcome, you might get a faster answer by showing a mockup of your expected results...

Comment: Sorry - should have shown what i wanted. i would like multiple columns but all the data on one row - i need to be be able to to extract from one table into a new table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab's solution is fine, I just wanted to show an alternative way of doing this. The following statement uses [subqueries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the information in one row:

```
SELECT
    [xxxx.name]=(SELECT value FROM dbo.parameter WHERE name='xxxxx.name'),
    [Event Name]=(SELECT dbo.contest.name
        FROM contest
        INNER JOIN open_box on open_box.contest_id = contest.id
        GROUP BY dbo.contest.name),
    [Total People]=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM open_option),
    [Total Scanned]=(SELECT SUM(scanned)
        FROM dbo.open_box
        GROUP BY contest_id),
    [Total Number]=(SELECT SUM(number)
        FROM dbo.open_box
        GROUP BY contest_id),
    Ref=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM open WHERE refer = 'True');
```

This requires the `Total Scanned` and `Total Number` to be queried seperately.

---

Update: if you then want to `INSERT` that into another table there are essentially two ways to do that.

1. Create the table directly from the `SELECT` statement:

---

```
SELECT
    -- the fields from the first query
INTO
    [database_name].[schema_name].[new_table_name]; -- creates table new_table_name
```

---

2. Insert into a table that already exists from the `INSERT`

---

```
INSERT INTO [database_name].[schema_name].[existing_table_name](
    -- the fields in the existing_table_name
)
SELECT
    -- the fields from the first query
```

Comment: @MalcolmHouston Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just `CROSS JOIN` the five queries as derived tables:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  Query1
) AS q1
CROSS JOIN (
  Query2
) AS q2
CROSS JOIN (...
```

Assuming that each of your individual queries only returns one row, then this `CROSS JOIN` should result in only one row.